# MVC Razor View with jQuery validation not validating empty fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have form built from a MVC model with a variety of validation requirements. If I enter the field and input an incorrect value (doesn't match regular expression or meet minimum length) the validation works just fine.

*What it's not doing is **validating the required fields** that are left empty*

Here's an excerpt of my model:

```
public partial class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
}
```

When I run `$("#OrderForm").validate().form()` it returns true when required fields are blank.

Here is the generated markup:

```
<form action="/Order/SubmitOrder" id="OrderForm" method="post">
<table width="400">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Contact Information</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="OrderInfo_ContactName">Name</label></td>
        <td><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="OrderInfo_ContactName" name="OrderInfo.ContactName" type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="OrderInfo_ContactEmail">Email</label></td>
        <td><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="Email is required" id="OrderInfo_ContactEmail" name="OrderInfo.ContactEmail" type="email" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="ordersubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here are my script tags:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/order.js"></script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In #OrderForm, Razor generate a "data-val-required" attribute?

Comment: Could you post your view markup? I take it your using jquery.validate.js

Comment: I've added the markup. I am using jquery.validate.js version 1.11.1. The data-val-required attribute is there which I expected to trigger an error if blank.

Answer (score 0):

This works out of the box for me but only when I've remember to include the bundle that includes all the unobtrusive and validation scripts. In a modern ASP.NET MVC there is a bundle called `~/bundles/jqueryval` which is defined as:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Make sure you include it either in your view or in your layout.

Comment: I've added the bundles. What's odd is that it will validate inputs with entered values, just not blank required fields.

Comment: You're saying even with all the libraries, it's still failing to catch blank inputs?

Comment: That's correct. I added the page script tags to the question

Comment: Just curious but why are you calling $("#OrderForm").validate().form() if you are using unobtrusive validation?

Answer (score 0):

I was initializing the validator in document.ready with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#OrderForm").removeAttr("novalidate");
    $("#OrderForm").validate({ ignore: [] });
});
```

Previously, a "novalidate" attribute was being added to my form. I'm not sure why. Once I removed those 2 lines it works as expected. I'm not sure why that is, it just is.

Thank you for input.